# How to get value from a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have table the row come from database so i don't know the number of the rows and there are button on every row

I want when user click the button i can know what row the user click, now the problem is when I use value to the button like this

```
<button id="edit" value="<?= $row['operation_id']; ?>">edit</button>
```

and the test script like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit").click(function(){
        data=("#edit").val();
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

but when click the button show this error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #edit has no method 'val'"

Comment: Mind the `$` on every jQuery call ... there is a missing `$` before `("#edit")`

Comment: thanks all for the answers ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

typo

```
data=("#edit").val();
    ^^^
```

missing the $

```
data = $("#edit").val();
```

or you can do

```
data = this.value;
data = $(this).val();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `$` to select element in `jQuery` as well as `var` keyword to initialize `data`:

```
var data = $(this).val();
```

Final code look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit").click(function(){
        var data = $(this).val();
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `$`. Your code should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit").click(function(){
        data=$(this).val();
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Here is [`Demo Code`](http://jsfiddle.net/NntCf/)

Answer (score 1):

Code below will be work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit").click(function(){
        var data = $("#edit").val();
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing something in your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit").click(function(){
        data=$("#edit").val();
        //...^...............
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/tXD78/1/)

You can simplify your code as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit").click(function(){
        data=this.value;
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/tXD78/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I generally do the following:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#edit").on('click', function () {                
            var data = $(this).val();
            console.log('clicked data: ' + data);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

There is typo mistake and you can use 'this' instead of selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#edit").click(function(){
    data= $("#edit").val();
     or
    data= this.val();
    alert(data);
  });
});
```